# How sign xdebug.so on Mac or turn off signature verification

Tags: php, xdebug, macos-catalina

After upgrading to MacOs 10.15 Catalina I found that xdebug.so (installed earlier by pecl) cannot started from command line:

```
php -version
Failed loading /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.10/pecl/20180731/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.10/pecl/20180731/xdebug.so, 0x0009): code signature in (/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/xdebug.so) not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.

PHP 7.3.8 (cli) (built: Aug 24 2019 19:38:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.8, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

So, all dependent launches (composer etc) finished with this error.

How to sign xdebug.so or turn off signature verification for xdebug.so?